# Best way to creating many documents in many interlinked collection in mongodb using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create documents in many collection in one go or one rest call.
Scenario is :
1. Trying to add user but along with it, i am trying to add wallet collection and cart collection. These 2 collection should contain user id, and user collection should contain wallet and cart ids. I have done a bit of work but its so lengthy that it don't seem the best way to go. Need suggestion for a way better than this.

```
exports.signupAUserMain = (req, res, next) => {
    User.find({ email: req.body.email }).exec()
        .then(result => {

            if (result.length !== 0) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    message: 'User is already present. Try with another email'
                })
            } else {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
                    if (err) {
                        return res.status(500).json({
                            message: 'Unable to encrypt password'
                        });
                    }

                    const user = new User({
                        _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                        firstName: req.body.firstName,
                        lastName: req.body.lastName,
                        role: req.body.role,
                        email: req.body.email,
                        password: hash
                    });

                    user.save()
                        .then(response => {

                            logger.customLogger('User created successfully');

                            const payback = new Paybackpoints({
                                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                                userId: response._id
                            })

                            payback.save()
                                .then(responseW => {
                                    logger.customLogger(`User created successully. Also payback wallet is created for the user,\n ${responseW}`);
                                    User.findByIdAndUpdate(response._id, { $set: { paybackId: responseW._id } }).exec()
                                        .then(responseupdation => {
                                            logger.customLogger(`Updated user with payback id`);

                                            const cart = new cart({
                                                _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                                                user: response._id
                                            })
                                            cart.save()
                                                .then(responseC => {
                                                    logger.customLogger(`User created successully. Also payback wallet and cart is created for the user,\n ${responseC}`);

                                                    res.status(201).json({
                                                        message: 'User created successully. Also payback wallet is created for the user',
                                                        wallet: responseW._id,
                                                        cart: responseC._id
                                                    })
                                                })
                                                .catch(error => {
                                                    res.status(500).json({
                                                        error
                                                    })
                                                })

                                        })


                                })

                                .catch(error => {
                                    User.findByIdAndRemove(response._id).exec()
                                        .then(result => {
                                            if (result) {
                                                logger.customLogger(`User creation rolled back as wallet creation got interrupted`);
                                                res.status(500).json({
                                                    message: 'User creation rolled back as wallet creation got interrupted',
                                                    error
                                                })
                                            }
                                        })
                                        .catch(newErr => {
                                            logger.customLogger(`Payback Wallet creation was unsuccessful and so user creation was trying to roll back to null but rather got interrupted`);
                                            res.status(500).json({
                                                message: 'Payback Wallet creation was unsuccessful and so user creation was trying to roll back to null but rather got interrupted',
                                                error1: error,
                                                error2: newErr
                                            })
                                        })

                                })
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            logger.customLogger(`Failed to create user, ${error}`)
                            res.status(500).json({
                                message: 'Failed to create user',
                                error
                            })

                        });
                })
            }


        })
        .catch(error => {
            logger.customLogger(error);
            res.status(500).json({
                error
            })
        })



}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you need to create custom `_id` and save that as mongo `_id` before saving documents.

> First create all custom 3 _id as following

```
const UserId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString(); 
const paybackId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
const cartId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId().toHexString();
```

> Set `_id` property `false` in Schema, Your all 3 Schema looks like as
>   following

```
const User = new mongoose.Schema({
    //need to add your remaning fields
    paybackId: String,
    cartId: String
},{ _id: false });

const Payback = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String
},{ _id: false });

const Cart = new mongoose.Schema({
    userId: String
},{ _id: false });
```

> Now you can insert all 3 with reference document parallel as per the following

```
let userObj = new User({
    _id: UserId, //5cd5308e695db945d3cc81a9
    paybackId: paybackId,
    cartId: cartId
});
userObj.save();

let paybackObj = new Payback({
    _id: paybackId,
    userId: UserId
});
paybackObj.save();

let cartObj = new Cart({
    _id: cartId,
    userId: UserId
});
cartObj.save();
```